# Blazor Server side app open in browser then shut down immediately if I'm having break points

Tags: blazor, breakpoints, shutdown

Why does my Blazor Server side app open in browser then shut down immediately if I'm having break points?
It just started to happen only when I'm having break points. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've not exactly presented a lot to go on!  Code on the break point?  Does it run without debugging?

Comment: clean your solution and retry

Answer (score 0):

Try updating nuget packages to the latest stable version. If you are working on .net 6 , check if your nuget packages are the latest version for that. They usually start with the number 6. If they start with the number 7 they could be for .net 7.

Note that if you upgrade a nuget package to a version that aims at .net 7 it will not work on .net 6.

for example one of my nugetpackes updates all the way to 7.13.0 but the highest one that starts with a 6 is 6.14.0 since i am working on .net 6 i would choose 6.14.0

Comment: I made sure all Microsoft nuget packages are 7 since the framework I'm working on is .Net7. I updated Visual Studio 2022 to the current version, Cleaned the solution, Rebuild. But I still get the same problem. This is the error message I get in the console: (process 47008) exited with code 0.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the issue is from the Chrome browser; most probably because it is not updated. When I switched to running on Edge, I was able to have breakpoints with no issue.